# Wicket textfield validator event

Tags: wicket, feedbackpanel

I have a Wicket form containing a text field.

I want that textfield to have a minimum of 3 characters.

In order to do that I have added a StringValidator as follows:

```
        newPersonName.add(StringValidator.minimumLength(3));
```

It works as it should and it even reports errors to my FeedbackPanel component.

The thing is that I want to be able to do something manual (some sort of log) when the validation fails, so I want to "Catch" the event of validation failure and add my own function there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply subclass `StringValidator` and override the `decorate` (Wicket 6) method.
In your example, it should look like the following :

```
newPersonName.add(new StringValidator(3, null){
    protected ValidationError decorate(ValidationError error, IValidatable<String> validatable){
         ValidationError superError = super.decorate(error, validatable);
         //log logic goes here
         return superError;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't seem to find the javadocs of "decorate" - where is this function located?

Comment: If you can't find this method, it might be because you're using Wicket 1.5, in such a case, you will need to override `onValidate` or similar.